# Angular 4.3 (Interceptor) pause request

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

Using Angular v6, also @angular/common/http

Trying to write interceptor which will check if token expired & if so send http request to server while other requests should wait.

Example in `token.interceptor.ts`

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

  if (this.tokenHasExpired) {
    if (!this.token) {
      return from('token').pipe(
        mergeMap(() => this.auth.refreshToken()),
        tap(() => {
          this.tokenHasExpired = false;
        }),
        mergeMap(() => next.handle(req)),
      );
    }
  }

  return next.handle(req);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? angular "url guards" can returns a promise which you can chain when calling any http requests

Comment: Added code example @BkSantiago

Comment: Http requests are treated as Observables in angular which are async in nature. I'm sure not if you can make them wait while 1 request is being processed.however you can prevent a component from being displayed by using Resolver.

Comment: have you found any solution for this ?

Comment: Still haven't found any solution